# Page numbering word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, headers

I have seen a lot of questions on page numbering in word 2010, and how to add them, so I know that. I have a particular question regarding the number of pages.

For example: I have a document of 5 pages, I want to insert page numbering on page 3 and I want to see the format of page numbering page x of y.

If I don this according the the many questions answered here, I start at page 3 with page 1 of 5, but what I really want to see is page 1 of 3, starting at page 3. Page 2 of 3 at page 4, and 3 of 3 at page 5, etc.

I couldnt find the answer on this specific question for far.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the field `NumPages` use the field `SectionPages` to get the number of pages in the current section. To change this e.g. edit the heading of the page, select the "y" and in the context menu select "edit field" or press Alt+F9. With multiple sections you'll start to recount the number of pages with each section.

For most forms of documents the number of pages does include anything that is upfront and just the numbering starts on different pages.

Another option would be to modify how the display for `NumPages` is calculated. To do this you'd use a field code (e.g. `{ = { NUMPAGES } - 1 }` - I had to use Ctrl+F9 to insert the second pair of braces) to modify the code that computes the total number of pages. The downside would be that you'd have to change it every time some page you don't want to count popups. See also the official help for [`NumPages`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-NumPages-field-536fa716-025b-4dd6-8a04-8a190b5b1490?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

For a better answer please supply some more information about the structure of your planned document. :)